# Bittorent tracker packaged for Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, packaging, bittorrent

I am looking for a bittorrent tracker that I can run on an Ubuntu server. Is one packaged for Ubuntu?

I have found the [Wikipedia list of bittorrent trackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_tracker_software), and as far as I can tell, none are downloadable via apt-get or the like.

I have downloaded and compiled the [source code for Torrust](https://github.com/torrust) and it looks to be working, but I would much prefer to just install a binary package that and expert has better integrated with Ubuntu.

I also took a look at [OpenTracker](https://erdgeist.org/gitweb/opentracker/tree/) and the lack of documentation or even autobuild configuration looks worrying.

The reason that I need bittorent is to move huge files on a firewalled corporate network. I cannot connect to a public tracker both because the files are confidential and due to the firewall. I don't need the tracker to support SSL, authentication, white/black lists etc because I am inside a corporate network and all clients are authorised.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the term, but isn't https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/qbittorrent the right software you are looking for?

Comment: qBittorrent should have a feature that allows you to use it as a private tracker: https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/How-to-use-qBittorrent-as-a-tracker

Comment: And there is a CLI version called [qBittorrent-nox](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/qbittorrent-nox).

Comment: Thanks @FedKad and Artur-Meinild those are helpful answers and look like they will solve my problem. Could you convert your comments to answers so that I can give you a +1